# Как получить авторские права на скрипт Python?

Tags: python, лицензирование

Как получить АП на скрипт **python**.

Или как сделать так чтобы его **не украли** и **не переписали под себя**?

Как **защитить скрипт от лишних глаз**?

Comment: Скрип python можно попробовать зашифровать, и сделать exe аншифр. А АП получить можно только платно если не ошибаюсь

Comment: Авторские права получать не нужно, они всегда есть по умолчанию сразу при создании программы. А шифровать нет смысла, всё равно расшифруют

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможны варианты:

1. Не прятать код. Положиться на честность пользователей, и/или угрозу юридических последствий. Четко прописать лицензию использования, заключать письменные контракты с пользователями. Если клиенты дорожат репутацией, то это работает.
2. Запутать свой код. Можно использовать автоматические запутыватели, например:
   https://pypi.org/project/python-obfuscator/
   Минусы: ненадежно (возможно, появится такой же автоматический распутыватель). Вызывает недовери у пользователей (которые не могут убедиться что ваш код не содержи ничего вредоносного). Вызывает недоверие у некоторых антивирусов.
3. Переписать свою программу на компилируемом языке программирования (например, С++). Минусы: предется все переписать. Компилируемый код тоже допускает исследование алгоритма, ходя это сложнее.
4. Не отдавать программу пользователю, а предоставлять сервис. (Не обязательно Web-service. Можно, например, заключать контракт на проведение расчетов.)
5. Продавать пользователю не программу, а устройство. Т.е. исполнять свою программу на отдельной машине, (arduino, или какой нибудь промышленный микроконтроллер) и общаться с основной машиной по usb. Минусы: вызывает недоверие о-очень много у кого.

Comment: Я делал web-starter. Он с сайта берёт код который раскидан по разным сайтам. и ещё делал его одноцветным с фоном. крч собирал в 1 прогу. А потом запускал

Comment: при помощи exec(#переменная с кодом который был в итоге)

Comment: одноцветным с фоном))))

Answer (score 1):

Зарегистрировать программу .exe например (скрипт не получится) как интеллектуальную собственность, естественно, если такой нету.

**Если необходимо то выложите программу на GitHub приватно.**

Comment: Возможно ли при помощи компилятора на С++ сделать программу на python?

Comment: Мой скрипт используется публично. Я бы не хотел чтобы его кто-то присвоил себе.

Comment: Самое простое ,  не давайте  свой скрипт никому.

Comment: @SoftwareSec, если ваши исходники попадают в интернет, в открытый доступ, это уже не ваш код ^^

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato что мне делать?

Comment: @SoftwareSec, не размещать их в интернете, наверное

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato моя программа является пользовательской

Comment: @SoftwareSec разве вы делаете не на Python? Если да, то используйте auto-py-to-exe.

Comment: @Alord данный способ мне не подходит. Так как во 1 антивирус не одобряет такой способ запуска файла который там используется. А во 2 у меня несколько файлов.

Answer (score 1):

Для версии 3.8 и свежее на данный момент не существует декомпилятора. Если скрипт не сложный то используйте `pyinstaller` или подобные упаковки.  Они вроде не пакуют исходник. А в рантайме только `pyc`,  который врятли смогут разобрать в ближайшие годы.

Если в скрипте что-то важное,  то скрипт дели на две части: модуль и запускалку. Модуль компилируй через `cython` в `pxd`. Запускалку в `pyc` или `exe`. В таком варианте декомпиляция подсилу только хакерам.

Comment: Я что-то не понял, а как же стандартный модуль dis? Он конечно не даёт полностью исходный код, но, думаю, его вывода достаточно, чтобы достаточно упёртый пользователь разобрал всё что его интересует

Comment: @andreymal LOAD_GLOBAL,LOAD_GLOBAL,LOAD_METHOD,LOAD_CONST,CALL_METHOD ..... тот кто это разберет быстрее сам напишет простую прогру, а если прога сложная - пункт 2 - в ситон)

Answer (score 0):

> Как получить АП на скрипт python.

**Статья 1259 ГК РФ "Объекты авторских прав"**

*4. Для возникновения, осуществления и защиты авторских прав не требуется регистрация произведения или соблюдение каких-либо иных формальностей.*

*В отношении программ для ЭВМ и баз данных возможна регистрация, осуществляемая по желанию правообладателя в соответствии с правилами статьи 1262 настоящего Кодекса.*

т.е. для возникновения у вас авторского права на код (именно код) от вас не требуется ничего дополнительного, авторские права, в том числе право авторства и право на имя возникают в момент создания вашего кода.

*3. Авторские права распространяются как на обнародованные, так и на необнародованные произведения, выраженные в какой-либо объективной форме, в том числе в письменной, устной форме (в виде публичного произнесения, публичного исполнения и иной подобной форме), в форме изображения, в форме звуко- или видеозаписи, в объемно-пространственной форме.*

т.е. если вы написали код и никуда публично его не выкладывали (например хранили дома) - авторское право всё равно возникает и охраняется государством.

**Закон РФ от 09.07.1993 N 5351-1 (ред. от 20.07.2004) "Об авторском праве и смежных правах"**

*Статья 9
Авторское право на произведение науки, литературы и искусства возникает в силу факта его создания.*

к сожалению в ГК РФ точную формулировку найти не смог (данная статья считается устаревшей, но ее содержимое переехало в ГК РФ)

т.е. как только вы написали свой код у вас автоматически появляются авторские права.

Кроме того в РФ возможно регистрация программ для ЭВМ

https://rospatent.gov.ru/ru/stateservices/gosudarstvennaya-registraciya-programmy-dlya-elektronnyh-vychislitelnyh-mashin-ili-bazy-dannyh-i-vydacha-svidetelstv-o-gosudarstvennoy-registracii-programmy-dlya-elektronnyh-vychislitelnyh-mashin-ili-bazy-dannyh-ih-dublikatov

а также после регистрации осуществляется дополнительная защита

**Статья 1261 ГК РФ**

*Авторские права на все виды программ для ЭВМ (в том числе на операционные системы и программные комплексы), которые могут быть выражены на любом языке и в любой форме, включая исходный текст и объектный код, охраняются так же, как авторские права на произведения литературы. Программой для ЭВМ является представленная в объективной форме совокупность данных и команд, предназначенных для функционирования ЭВМ и других компьютерных устройств в целях получения определенного результата, включая подготовительные материалы, полученные в ходе разработки программы для ЭВМ, и порождаемые ею аудиовизуальные отображения.*

> Или как сделать так чтобы его не украли и не переписали под себя?

Я бы поставил вопрос по другому - ***как доказать (в суде), что я являюсь автором объекта авторского права***, потому что доказал факт авторства вы можете очень многое (запретить использование, распространение и т.д. ПО, требовать компенсации и т.п.)

Для этого вы можете:

1. выложить свой код в каком-нибудь хранилище (типа GitHub), которое позволяет однозначно установить время загрузки (чтобы показать свое первенство)
2. иногда делают так (правда больше для произведений, а не для исходников программ) - распечатываете свой код, запечатываете в письме, отправляете почтой себе же и получив храните не распаковывая письмо, важен факт целостности конверта и печати Почты РФ - это опять же однозначно доказывает первенство создания объекта авторского права

> Как защитить скрипт от лишних глаз?

используйте разные обфускаторы, но проблема скриптовых языков в том, что деобфускация делается гораздо проще, чем с компилируемыми языками

опять же ничто не мешает провести обратную разработку

P.S.

главное понимать, что при необходимости всё можно украсть/переделать и т.д. и в определённой степени защиты от этого не существует - т.е. затраты на защиту могут превысить возможные потери, а вот получить доказательства нарушения вашего права - это гораздо проще и надежнее